# Android AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

**Есть следующий код**

```
mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mAnswerEditText.getText())
                        || TextUtils.isEmpty(mEmailEditText.getText()))
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            "Заполните поля ответа и email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else if (!isValidEmail(mEmailEditText.getText())) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            "Укажите правильный email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    String[] strings = {
                            mAnswerEditText.getText().toString(),
                            mEmailEditText.getText().toString(),
                            mAd.getEmail()};

                    new CreateAdTask().execute(strings);

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            "Сообщение отправлено!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            }
        });  

private class CreateAdTask extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String[]... params) {
            ServerHelper.getInstance().sendAnswer(
                    params[0].toString(),
                    params[1].toString(),
                    params[2].toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Логи ошибки**

```
08-24 09:08:11.029 14188-14259/com.likhanov.adservice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                                                                        Process: com.likhanov.adservice, PID: 14188
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
                                                                            at com.likhanov.adservice.AdFragment$CreateAdTask.doInBackground(AdFragment.java:96)
                                                                            at com.likhanov.adservice.AdFragment$CreateAdTask.doInBackground(AdFragment.java:91)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Строка 96 - это params[0].toString(). Не могу понять почему я выхожу за границы массива в этом месте. Видимо надо как-то по другому передать параметры, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запись `String[]... params` означает, что вы можете передать в метод неопределённое число параметров. И в переменной `params` будет массив этих параметров типа `String[]`.

То есть для доступа к параметрам, переданным способом как у вас, запись должна быть такой:

```
params[0][0].toString();
params[0][1].toString();
params[0][2].toString();
```

Либо вы можете изменить сигнатуру метода на `doInBackground(String... params)` и передавать в него данные так:

```
new CreateAdTask().execute(mAnswerEditText.getText().toString(),
                           mEmailEditText.getText().toString(),
                           mAd.getEmail());
```

А получать их так, как вы делаете это сейчас.

Comment: Спасибо, работает.